# Obtener nombre de mes en Español (Laravel, Carbon)

Tags: laravel, carbon

Alguien sabe como obtener el nombre del mes de una fecha en español utilizando **Carbon** y **Laravel**.

Actualmente uso:

```
$fecha = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($data["Fecha"])
$mes = $fecha->format("F");
```

Pero me devuelve el nombre del mes en inglés

También he probado con [image: esto]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creo que la solución mas factible es esta:

No me funciona las opciones que uds. me brindaron, y realmente urge.

```
$meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
$fecha = Carbon::parse($inputs['Fecha']);
$mes = $meses[($fecha->format('n')) - 1];
$inputs['Fecha'] = $fecha->format('d') . ' de ' . $mes . ' de ' . $fecha->format('Y');
```

Comment: te recomiendo revises la respuesta de @Dev.Joel pues yo la he implementado y si me sirvio

Comment: No me funciona, quisiera subir una imagen pero no se como hacerlo aquí para mostrarte que no me funciona.

Comment: @AlfredoPaz ya modifique la pregunta para que veas la imagen.

Comment: @AbrahamRosales si no funciona tiene que ver con detalles de su servidor en donde esta ejecutando _(instalación del paquete de idioma )_

Answer (score 6):

Yo lo solucione agregando en el AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    // Configuración para fechas en español
    Carbon::setUTF8(true);
    Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_MX', 'es', 'ES', 'es_MX.utf8');

}
```

`Carbon::setLocale` establece el lenguaje para `diffForHumans()`

`setlocale` establece el lenguaje para `formatLocalized('%B')` pero solo funciona si en el servidor esta instalada alguna de las localizaciones listadas. En el caso de Ubuntu 18.04 se instala el lenguaje 'es_MX.utf8' [Guia para instalar lenguajes en linux](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-locales/)

Answer (score 4):

`Carbon` usa el método estático `setLocale` solo para algunos de sus métodos como `diffForHumans()` más no para `format` , es decir

```
Carbon::setLocale('es');
$fecha = Carbon::parse('03-04-2018');
$fecha->diffForHumans(); //esto se mostrará en español
$fecha->format("F"); // Inglés.
```

Para realizar el formato debe hacer eso de [setLocale](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php) de la siguiente forma, pero  el método `format` seguirá en el mismo idioma, en su lugar debería utilizar el método `formatLocalized` que hace uso de [strftime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php) además de añadir  el .[formato](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php) que desee  *(%B para el nombre del mes)*

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
$fecha = Carbon::parse('03-04-2018');
$fecha->format("F"); // Inglés.
$mes = $fecha->formatLocalized('%B');// mes en idioma español
```

> además puede revisar el [siguiente paquete Jenssegers/date](https://github.com/jenssegers/date) para
>   manejar idioma en fechas con Laravel.

Comment: Joel solo te hago un comentario, yo debí dejar la siguiente linea así, de otro modo me indicaba que la clase Carbon no existia `$fecha = Carbon\Carbon::parse('03-04-2018');`

Comment: @AlfredoPaz se deberá importar la clase con use `use Carbon\Carbon;`  , usando  la opción que dices no hay necesidad de realizar la realizar la importación, Igual gracias por el comentario.

Comment: sip lo se solo queria hacerte el comentario

Comment: No me funcionó, inclusive copié y pegué el código pero el nombre del mes me aparece en inglés ("April").

Answer (score 4):

Ya se que es demasiado tarde intenté de todo como tú y al final di con varias cosillas una es tener el locale en el idioma que quieres checa
****app.php
locale es****

luego en
*AppServiceProvider.php*

añadí esto en la función *boot*
`Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));`

ya después en mi controller

```
$fecha = Carbon::parse($fSalida);
$date = $fecha->locale(); //con esto revise que el lenguaje fuera es 
dd($fecha->monthName); //y con esta obtengo el mes al fin en español!
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola prueba con lo siguiente:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES"); 
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('es'); 
$fecha = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($data["Fecha"])
$mes = $fecha->format("F");
```

**Ojo**: Si tienes un archivo de configuración, trata de llamar el método setlocale desde allí.

Comment: Si, si hay cun archivo de configuración, sin embargo ya probe lo que mencionas pero no funciona.

Comment: Prueba ingresar al archivo de configuración: **/app/config/app.php** y cambiar la propiedad 'locale' => 'es',

Comment: ya esta en `es`

Answer (score 2):

Para que funcione en español tienes que poner lo siguiente en `AppServiceProvider.php`.

En la funcion `boot`:

```
    Public function boot()
    {
      \Carbon::setUTF8(true);
      \Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
      setlocale(LC_TIME, config('app.locale'));
    }
```

Para probar en tu vista puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
    {{ $date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()}}
    {{$date->formatLocalized('%B')}} //nombre del mes actual
```

Recuerda colocar tu idioma en config/app.php lo siguiente:

`'locale' => 'es',`

Answer (score 0):

no se si a estas altura sera de uilidad, pero puedes obtener el nombre del mes de esta manera:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->locale('es');
echo $date->monthName;
```

o

```
$date = new Carbon('fecha')->locale('es');
echo $date->monthName;
```

Aqui te dejo el link:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Answer (score 0):

File **AppServiceProvider** in function **boot**
put

```
Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_MX', 'es', 'ES', 'es_MX.utf8');
```

after in file **.blade.php** or **.php**
use Carbon:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y %I:%M %p') }}
```

output example: **27 Septiembre 2021 09:42 a.m.**

Comment: Gracias por tomar el tiempo en responder. Estas en el sitio en español, seria bueno editaras la respuesta y colocaras el texto en el idioma oficial. Por otra parte responder con solo código sin explicar un poco se considera baja calidad. Revisa [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Si quiere una solución rápida puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
        $hoy = Carbon::now();

        $mes = $hoy->month;

        switch ($mes) {
            case 1:
                $mes = 'Enero';
                break;
            case 2:
                $mes = 'Febrero';
                break;
            case 3:
                $mes = 'Marzo';
                break;
            case 4:
                $mes = 'Abril';
                break;
            case 5:
                $mes = 'Mayo';
                break;
            case 6:
                $mes = 'Junio';
                break;
            case 7:
                $mes = 'Julio';
                break;
            case 8:
                $mes = 'Agosto';
                break;
            case 9:
                $mes = 'Septiembre';
                break;
            case 10:
                $mes = 'Octubre';
                break;
            case 11:
                $mes = 'Noviembre';
                break;
            case 12:
                $mes = 'Diciembre';
                break;
        }
```

No olvides importar `use Carbon\Carbon;` en tu controlador.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser así:

```
$course->created_at->locale('es')->isoFormat(('MMMM Y'))
```

Resultado es enero 2023

Otra forma pero el resultado es igual es:

```
$course->created_at->locale('es')->translatedFormat(('M Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

En versiones más modernas de Carbon la función `formatLocalized` ha sido marcada como "deprecated".
Ahora se puede sacar el nombre del mes en español con la propiedad `monthName`, especificándole antes el `locale`.

```
$fecha = Carbon::parse($data["Fecha"])
$mes = $fecha->locale('es_ES')->monthName // mayo
```