# Obtener el nombre del día en español de una fecha (carbon laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Esto es lo que he intentado de otras respuestas, pero no me funciona:

```php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES'); 
$fecha = Carbon::parse('03-04-2018');
$dia = $fecha->formatLocalized('%A');
```

Comment: mira si te sirve alguna de estas opciones https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200149/obtener-nombre-de-mes-en-espa%C3%B1ol-laravel-carbon

Answer (score 0):

Debes verificar que en el servidor tengas instalado los locales a los que haces refencia desde PHP.

Si usas un servidor debian/ubuntu puedes comprobarlo ejecutando:

```
locale -a
```

si no los tienes instalados:

```
apt-get install -y locales-all
```

Comment: servidor?? estoy trabajando desde el localhost

Comment: Entonces en tu máquina local, PHP usa los locales del sistema operativo. [enlace](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale). "The default locale is set to be the system locale on that platform."